# Shopping cart - Drag and Drop bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have implemented jQuery's shopping card based on the example: http://jsfiddle.net/RR6z5/1/

But there is a little bug. When I drag an element from products to shopping card and then **without drop**, I drag from shopping card to products, the original element from Product dissapears. How to avoid this?

Thanks.

```
$(function () {
$("#catalog").accordion();
$("#catalog li").draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone"
});
$("#cart ol").droppable({
    out: function (event, ui) {
        var self = ui;
        ui.helper.off('mouseup').on('mouseup', function () {
            $(this).remove();
            self.draggable.remove();
        });
    },
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.draggable.is('.dropped')) return false;
        $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
        $("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this).draggable({
            appendTo: "body",
            helper: "clone"
        }).addClass('dropped');
    }
}).sortable({
    items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
    sort: function () {
        // gets added unintentionally by droppable interacting with sortable
        // using connectWithSortable fixes this, but doesn't allow you to customize active/hoverClass options
        $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
    }
});


});
```

Comment: If I am right, you want to solve the problem that, if you start dragging an item but not drop it into the #cart element, the original item will disappear.

Comment: Yes, any idea to fix that?

Comment: Have already answered. Don't you see the Answer list...

Comment: Yes Tom, sorry. Perfect answer, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that I amend something:

```
if(self.draggable.parents('#cart').length){
     self.draggable.remove();
}
```

The query make sure that the element being dragged in #cart element, then remove it.

If the dragged element is a original one(which must be not in `#cart` element but in `#products` element), that element won't be removed.

```
$(function () {
    $("#catalog").accordion();
    $("#catalog li").draggable({
        appendTo: "body",
        helper: "clone"
    });
    $("#cart ol").droppable({
        out: function (event, ui) {
            var self = ui;
            ui.helper.off('mouseup').on('mouseup', function () {
                $(this).remove();
                if(self.draggable.parents('#cart').length){
                    self.draggable.remove();
                }
            });
        },
        activeClass: "ui-state-default",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.draggable.is('.dropped')) return false;
            $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
            $("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this).draggable({
                appendTo: "body",
                helper: "clone"
            }).addClass('dropped');
        }
    }).sortable({
        items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
        sort: function () {
            // gets added unintentionally by droppable interacting with sortable
            // using connectWithSortable fixes this, but doesn't allow you to customize active/hoverClass options
            $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
        }
    });


});
```

You can check it on http://jsfiddle.net/RR6z5/30/

Answer (score 0):

Try this extension [Drag and Drop to cart](http://mage-extensions-themes.com/extensions/drag-and-drop-cart.html) .It will help you to drag multiple products and at one click all the products are added to cart.